# How to insert a row in Google Sheets and copy formulas up or down?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a script to insert new row, before or after a specified row, and keep all formulas that are in different columns.

Which is strange is I managed to do this for inserting a row before :

```
function insertRowBefore() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("sommaire_redac");
  var firstRow = sh.getRange('N2').getValue();
  var formulas = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getFormulas();
  sh.insertRowsBefore(firstRow, 1);
  sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).setFormulas(formulas);
  sh.setCurrentCell(sh.getRange('N2'));
};
```

This seems to work quite well.

But not for inserting a row after :

```
function insertRowAfter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("sommaire_redac");
  var firstRow = sh.getRange('P2').getValue();
  var rowAfter = sh.getRange('P2').getValue()+1;
  var formulas = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getFormulasR1C1();
  sh.insertRowsAfter(firstRow, 1);
  sh.getRange(rowAfter, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).setFormulasR1C1(formulas);
  sh.setCurrentCell(sh.getRange('N2'));
};
```

There I thought I would need R1C1 notation, anyway with standard notation I can't get relative cell references, so it does not work.

Which is even stranger is that my insertRowAfter function seems to work as well, except that I have a message error ("ERROR : formula parse error") in each cell of the new row. Whereas in this new row I do get the right data, the right formulas!

Comment: `insertRowsBefore` [accepts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowsBefore(Integer,Integer)) the position of the cell, that you want to insert the new row before or after, as the first argument. You're using `getValue()`, which will get the cell content and not the position. What does your `N2` cell have in the `sommaire_redac` sheet?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Range.getFormulasR1C1()` and `Range.setFormulaR1C1()`, like this:

```
function test() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sommaire_redac');
  const rowNumberCell = sheet.getRange('N2');
  const rowNumber = rowNumberCell.getValue();
  insertRowWithFormulas_(sheet, rowNumber, 'before');
  sheet.setCurrentCell(rowNumberCell);
}


/**
* Inserts a row before of after rowNumber in sheet, copying formulas from rowNumber.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {Number} rowNumber The 1-indexed position of a row in the sheet.
* @param {String} insert Optional. Use 'before' to insert a row before rowNumber, 'after' to insert after rowNumber.
*/
function insertRowWithFormulas_(sheet, rowNumber, insert = 'before') {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 25 October 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74196134/13045193
  const [action, rowOffset] = insert === 'before' ? ['insertRowsBefore', 0] : ['insertRowsAfter', 1];
  const range = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  const formulas = range.getFormulasR1C1().flat();
  sheet[action](rowNumber, 1);
  formulas.forEach((formula, index) => {
    if (formula) {
      range.offset(rowOffset, index, 1, 1).setFormulaR1C1(formula);
    }
  });
}
```